# .NET .vbproj vs .sln

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the difference between a .vbproj and a .sln file?

Comment: vbproj = project file, sln = solution file. A solution can have multiple projects

Comment: In my opinion, yeah it is a bad question, as this info can be found anywhere on the net with some googling. However some people also thought it was a well researched and interesting question (cannot imagine who though). Since you got some answers and one elaborate one, you should now [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

A vbproj is a project file for a single project. A solution file can contain many projects in it, vb or otherwise, as well as have other references to things like solution files.

You can open either in a text editor.

Here is a solution file, you'll see it contains csharp and vb project files. It also contains the various configurations for the builds as seen in the configuration manager, such as debug or release, and the target platforms for  those builds.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26430.6
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "cert", "cert\cert.csproj", "{BF281F9F-13B5-4F4C-BB18-96E07B3C6F8D}"
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "certvb", "certvb\certvb.vbproj", "{439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}"
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "WindowsApp1", "WindowsApp1\WindowsApp1.vbproj", "{9AE70A5C-7541-407C-913D-E1B60BCB296F}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsFormsApp1Cs", "WindowsFormsApp1Cs\WindowsFormsApp1Cs.csproj", "{E12A5ADD-3CB2-485B-B23C-55E49BC263A7}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {BF281F9F-13B5-4F4C-BB18-96E07B3C6F8D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {BF281F9F-13B5-4F4C-BB18-96E07B3C6F8D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {BF281F9F-13B5-4F4C-BB18-96E07B3C6F8D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {BF281F9F-13B5-4F4C-BB18-96E07B3C6F8D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {9AE70A5C-7541-407C-913D-E1B60BCB296F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {9AE70A5C-7541-407C-913D-E1B60BCB296F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {9AE70A5C-7541-407C-913D-E1B60BCB296F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {9AE70A5C-7541-407C-913D-E1B60BCB296F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E12A5ADD-3CB2-485B-B23C-55E49BC263A7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E12A5ADD-3CB2-485B-B23C-55E49BC263A7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E12A5ADD-3CB2-485B-B23C-55E49BC263A7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E12A5ADD-3CB2-485B-B23C-55E49BC263A7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

On the other hand the project files themselves are xml and contain settings, references, files and other information for the individual project within the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{439C487E-5DA6-4998-93B5-B482A2A8C40A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>certvb.Module1</StartupObject>
    <RootNamespace>certvb</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>certvb</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <MyType>Console</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>certvb.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>certvb.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionExplicit>On</OptionExplicit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionCompare>Binary</OptionCompare>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionStrict>Off</OptionStrict>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionInfer>On</OptionInfer>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\cert\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ChainDownloader.vb" />
    <Compile Include="Module1.vb" />
    <Compile Include="My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
    <Compile Include="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="My Project\Application.myapp">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Application.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="My Project\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <CustomToolNamespace>My</CustomToolNamespace>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **.sln** is your solution.It can contain multiple project.

While,

The **.vbproj** is your project. It contains the files needed for the project.